# How to get particular list index in java?

Tags: java

Consider following code:

```
public class UserJMXBeanImpl implements UserJMXBean {

private  List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

public  void addUser(User user){
    userList.add(user);

}


public  List<User> getUserList() {

    return userList;
}

public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
    this.userList = userList;
}
}
```

The get method of this code gives this value: [image: debugger]

I need to use only roles and userID values and take it further for my operations. When I change my return type of get method to `return userList.get(0).getUserId()` my return type changes.

How can I do that?

Comment: The full content of your question must go **in** the question, not just linked. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: firstly you should change "private  List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();" to "private  List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();"

Comment: @Mihai, that's a Java 7 Feature. He can leave the diamond brackets empty for the constructor.

Comment: am i the only one who doesnt understand his question? what you want to do exactly?

Comment: @user2504380 that makes two of us.

Comment: @user2504380 me too.

Comment: @Omoro I need to parse only two elements without changing the return type. Or is there any other way to approach this so that my output only shows two elements(roles and userID).

Comment: @Mena  I need to parse only two elements without changing the return type. Or is there any other way to approach this so that my output only shows two elements(roles and userID).

Comment: @lifeatstake still not clear I'm afraid.

Comment: Maybe another approach to point you to the right direction: A) By which parameter do you want to search for the required user (in other words, do you want to find the user f.e. by name?) ? B) Are you allowed to implement a new method, therefor extending the class' visible interface ?

Comment: @SME_Dev Yes I am allowed to write more codes. And I need user by name and role.

Comment: @lifeatstake I would create a new class to hold the elements(roles and userID). Then when you loop the user list and based on your parsing as you put it, you can add the elements(roles and userID) objects into a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are al least 4 options:

a) From the code, that is accessing UserJMXBean:

```
String searchName="Hubert";
String searchRole="Admin";

UserJMXBean bean = new UserJMXBeanImpl();

for(User user : bean.getUserList()){
    if(user.getName().equals(searchName) && user.getRole().equals(searchRole)){
        //do something with your user
        String userID = user.getID();
    }
}
```

b) Add a new method to your UserJMXBeanImpl and the UserJMXImplBean and return the user instance:

```
public User findUser(String name, String role){
    for(User user : this.getUserList()){
        if(user.getName().equals(name) && user.getRole().equals(role)){
            return user;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

c) Add a new method to your UserJMXBeanImpl and the UserJMXImplBean and return the required attributes:

```
public String[] getUserAttributes(String name, String role){
    for(User user : this.getUserList()){
        if(user.getName().equals(name) && user.getRole().equals(role)){
            return new String[]{user.getID(), 
                                user.getRole(),
                                user.getEmail()}
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

d) You can overload the existing method and return a size-1-list:

```
public  List<User> getUserList(String name, String role) {
    for(User user : this.getUserList()){
        if(user.getName().equals(name) && user.getRole().equals(role)){
            List<User> list = new ArrayList<>(1);
            list.add(user);
            return list;
        }
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Comment: C) option helped. I wrote as this:

      `public String[] getUserAttributes(){

       for(User user : this.getUserList()){
       return new String[]{user.getUserId(),user.getRoles()};
       }

       return null;

       }`

Answer (score 0):

You are making confusion. The get method should remain as it is, it can be invoked to return the list that is an instance variable and can only be accessed by the getter method. Maybe what you want is another method, like:

```
public List<String> extractUserFields(User user){
    List<String> fields = new List<String>();
    fields.add(user.getId());
    fields.add(user.getRole());
    return fields;
}
```

Or maybe get userList as parameter for the method and extract the user you want from there.

EDIT: another suggestion. The way you tried to do that is wrong for another reason. Always remember to keep the name of the methods coherent with what it's supposed to do. You wanted your getList method to return the ID and roles fields of the first element. It's wrong, because the method name, when you code with someone else or when you will check your own code in months, will lead to understanding errors.

Imagine a method like this and think how harmful this practice can be:

```
public String getBombLocation(Bomb bomb){
    bomb.explode();
    return "BOOM!";
    }
```

Comment: While this concept is ok, the example method doesn't fit his description. A user seems to have multiple roles and a unique id. Also I'd expect, that Role is another class instead of String. However, the OP's description is suboptimal.

Comment: of course it was a simple example to show him how to think in a conceptual way. I don't think he will have problems in changing the List type to best fit his needs!